# How to easily label bar plot using data frame column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, graph

I have got the pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
     pos1   pos2   pos3   pos4   pos5 aa1 aa2 aa3 aa4 aa5
0   38.81  16.08  12.33   8.35   7.95   A   T   N   F   P
1   45.51  41.48   5.34   2.27   1.65   A   T   V   F   I
2   41.14  22.27   9.38   6.93   6.08   T   D   V   N   P
3   37.84  19.77  14.26  13.64  11.53   V   E   Q   L   A
4   35.74  28.75  14.09   9.72   4.89   G   N   P   D   E
5   52.44  13.98  11.88   8.64   8.18   G   S   Q   H   D
6   40.28  13.58  11.70  10.85   8.75   T   N   E   V   I
7   57.44  25.06  13.98   1.99   1.08   V   I   M   T   A
8   55.68  10.80  10.11   9.55   7.39   H   Q   K   T   N
9   96.02   2.50   0.74   0.17   0.17   F   Q   I   L   V
10  57.27  13.92   9.72   6.82   4.94   K   Q   E   N   V
11  67.61  12.95  11.93   3.98   0.97   E   V   T   K   I
12  63.52  25.57   9.38   0.80   0.28   V   I   L   A   T
13  51.93  44.26   1.70   0.80   0.80   V   I   H   T   D
14  38.81  20.97  15.91  12.44   8.35   N   D   A   E   S
15  73.12  13.86   4.49   2.84   1.59   A   E   T   S   Y
```

which gives the bar plot plotted with matplotlib:

[image: Bar plot from the dataframe]

However, I would like to use columns aa1 - aa5 to be used as an internal labels for each segment of single bar. Is it possible to do it in similar way as it was done in the [matplotlib tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) but for all the colors of the bar? I was trying to fix the label position regarding the percentage of the bar but it didn't really work. I look forward for some ideas!

EDIT:
What I would like to do is shown in the graph below only for column 1 and 4:
[image: The aim of this question]

Comment: I find this rather hard to understand. What do the letters signify? How should the plot look like according to those letters?

Comment: The data describes the distribution of each letter at each position. I would like to label the distribution by the letter is belongs to.

Comment: There are already questions on how to label bar plots. In how far do they not help?

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to get the annotations right where you want them, but here's an example that may help. I've used some dummy data, so you'll have to ensure it works for your data, although it's in a similar shape.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import string

# dummy data
no_bars = 15
no_stacked = 5
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, 20, (no_bars, no_stacked)), columns=['pos1', 'pos2', 'pos3', 'pos4', 'pos5'])

#random letters in a dataframe
ltrs = pd.DataFrame([random.sample(list(string.ascii_uppercase), no_bars) for _ in range(no_stacked)])

ax = df.plot.bar(stacked=True, width=.8)

#annotate each 'patch' one by one (1D
j = 0
i = 0
for lbl in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(ltrs.iloc[j, i], (lbl.get_x()+.2, lbl.get_y()+.3), color='white')
    i+=1
    if i == no_bars:
        j += 1
        i = 0
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, 0.85, 1])
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, .5))

plt.show()
```

[image]